# How to target elements

Tags: jquery, ios

This question is about **touch events** in a list menu with sub-menus. The intent is to have action (on mobile devices) with one touch -> extend, 2nd touch retract. Touch another item -> it extends & previous retracts.

Here's the problem: iPad 4.3.3 works great. iPhone 5.1 & Android 4 - 2nd touch retracts and extends. Not the desired effect. Check out an [example here](https://flydata.mobi/bella/) from your mobile device. Thanks for looking.

Is this a bug in jQuery or the mobile OS's ?

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
    if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android/i))) {
        $('#nav li').click(function(){
            // attach a click event listener to provoke iPhone/iPod/iPad's hover event
            // Amended the next 3 lines 
            var $this_li = $(this);  
            $('#nav li ul').slideUp(function() {
                $('ul', $this_li).slideDown();
            });
        });
    } else {
        // This part works in non-mobile browser
        $('#nav li').hover(
            function () {
                //show its submenu
                $('ul', this).slideDown(200);
            }, 
            function () {
                //hide its submenu
                $('ul', this).slideUp(200);         
            }
        ); 
    }  
});
```

Comment: You need another if statement for the browsers that arent working right with your code.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for what the improved jquery might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several trial and error hours, the following changes finally had the desired effect to mirror hover events on touch devices. That is, for an menu item with sub-menu (using id's and without class attributes):

1. If sub-menu is up (hidden), slideDown.
2. If sub-menu is down (visible), slideUp.
3. If one sub-menu is down and another is selected, hide the down & slide down the selected.

   ```
   $('#nav li').click(function() {
       var $selected_li = $(this); 
       if ($('ul', $selected_li).is(':visible')) {
           $('#nav li ul').slideUp();
       }
       else {
           $('#nav li ul').slideUp(function() {
               $('ul', $selected_li).slideDown();
           });
       }
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var $this_li = $(this);  
 $('#nav li ul').slideUp(function() {
     $('ul', $this_li).slideDown();
 });
```

This code is doing what its supposed to, you are telling $(this) to slidedown,
but you are also capturing the same item in the slide up so its slides up then down.

try this instead loop through the collection of nav items
slide up all of them but the clicked one, and slide down only the clicked one.

```
//...in the click event
var $this_li = $(this);  
$('#nav li').each(function(index) {
    if ( this != $this_li ) {
        $('ul', this).slideUp();
    }
    else {
        $('ul', $this_li).slideDown();
    }   
});
```

Im no jquery expert but that should be pretty close.

Comment: Thanks. (You'd consider me a novice.) That looks like it'd work, however now the sub-menus (products & testimonials) won't slideDown. See the [example here](https://flydata.mobi/bella). I've added an alert to both branches.

Comment: Yeah I see that - looks like this is not working should it be

if ( $(this) != $this_li )  like I said not a jquery expert that might fix it jquery has to wrap the this pointer Im pretty sure.

Comment: Thanks again. That still has something incorrect. Same result. `slideUp()` gets called over 10 times...

Comment: thats because your not using classes to identify your menus.  But it should find 'itself' and wind up everyone besides itself and then drop itself down..not sure why that wouldnt work